# modrewrite on cshtml files are ignored by mod_mono

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mod-mono

I've got mod_mono and mono installed on my webserver and I'm trying to get this simple modrewrite working, however it seems to be ignored by mod mono.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^Projects/page1.cshtml$    /project2    [PT]
```

I have that in my .htaccess in the document root. If I use any other extension besides .cshtml, it works as intended. Any ideas?